# flash base path issues

Tags: flash

I have a **flash file in folder "/"** which **loads another flash** file in folder **"/xyz/"**.
The **second** flash file will load several resource files on its own.

Now flash is **looking** for the resource files **at the base folder "/"** and **instead of** the other loaded flash's folder **"/xyz/"**.

The second loaded flash file is provided by a third party and can't be modified.

How do I solve this?
Is there any way to dynamically change the base folder of the "application" at run-time? Or am I stuck in a dead-end?

I've heard about the html swf tag "BASE" so I've tried loading the second flash file with a ".....?BASE=/xyz/" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with your comments about the technology since by not having access to the swf code, you're technically not accessing the technology itself. It's a bit like stating that a car sucks because you don't have the keys :)

In any case, I answered a similar question last week, hope it helps!
[pass a base path to a swf loaded at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153241/pass-a-base-path-to-a-swf-loaded-at-runtime/4153541#4153541)

In your particular case, the idea is to have symlinks in the base folder, that would create "aliases" pointing to /xyz/, this way you don't have to copy the assets , simply point to them so that they can be accessed either directly by the second swf or indirectly when loaded via the main swf. Of course , if each loaded swf has a different relative folder, you would have to create a different set of symlinks for each of them!

As for developing in Flash, I doubt it's any more difficult than developing with another platform, it all depends on what you're trying to achieve, but as I was pointing out earlier , loading third party swfs is hardly considered Flash development.

Your problem is also suggesting that the swfs weren't developed with the intention to be loaded by a third swf, there are ways to pass parameters to a loaded swf and it should have been very easy to implement a dynamic way to load the contained swf assets urls.

Comment: Well, the "technology" comments are more in general frustration on flash.. It's really a nightmare to develop anything with it. Your solution is pretty yet if I understand you correctly you're suggesting me to change these symlinks as required at run-time. What happens when there are several dozens of request (to load) at the same time? I mean, each loaded "module" needs different folder (relative to itself), so your solution might work if I know that only one request happens at a time. I could simulate a "locking" mechanism from the loader side, but that would slow things down big-time.

Comment: Either way you got my +1 for a creative "almost-solution" (:

Answer (score 0):

The base folder is the folder where your HTML file (that has the Flash SWF embedded in it) is located.

You can supply it as an embed parameter (in the HTML embedd or swfobject)

`"base=http://www.yourdomain.com/flashfolder"`

Here's some more [info about embed parameters](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html).

### Update

In reply to your comment, Unless you have access to the code for each of those SWF's you won't be able to do that.

Comment: I know about it and it doesn't fit me because I'm about to load several sub-applications, each in a different folder.

Comment: added a reply to the answer. I initially thought you could change the base path inside with AS3, but you cannot.

Comment: Hah - great answer (: On a serious note, thanks for at least trying. This technology (if you can call it that way) seem to be very unpopular, and we certainly see why. Thank you again, hope someone else with an answer comes in.

Comment: Well, this problem is due to security concerns, but the big problems with flash are accessibility and interop with other technologies. Resource/CPU hogging isn't so great either ;)